# can torque pbs output error messages to file in real time

Tags: configuration, pbs, torque

The errors and results are written into *.err(PBS -e) and *.out(PBS -o) files, after the torque pbs jobs are finished.

Can torque pbs output ERROR messages to *.err in real time when jobs are running ?

Can torque pbs output OUTPUT messages to *.out in real time when jobs are running ?

How to config pbs_server or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to set

```
$spool_as_final_name true
```

in the config file for the mom's. This is located in /mom_priv/config. This is [documented here.](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/12-appendices/parameters.htm?TocPath=Appendices%7CAppendix%20C%3a%20Node%20manager%20%28MOM%29%20configuration%7C_____1)