# How to view progress of .jar job on torque clusterr

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, cluster-computing, torque

I am running a `.jar` files on a torque cluster. They will run for an unknown amount of time.

I want to check the progress of the job while it is running. How do I do this? Obviously `system.out.println` doesn't work which is what I would usually use if running locally.

I use Ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251810/can-torque-pbs-output-error-messages-to-file-in-real-time

Answer (score 0):

Print the output to a file instead of standard out. This is what I achieve it before.